# For what $d$ does $\sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\left[I_{|m|}\left(\frac{t}{d}\right)\right]^d \;\mathrm dt$ converge?

Tags: calculus, probability, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, bessel-functions

For what $d\in\mathbb{N}$ does the following expression have a finite value?

$$u(d)=\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\left[I_{|m|}\left(\frac{t}{d}\right)\right]^d \;\mathrm dt$$

$I_n(t)$ is a [modified Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions) of the first kind. For the context of the question, in case this is useful, I was attempting to solve the problem *'If $d$ people stand next to each other in a line and play a game where at each step they [uniformly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution) randomly choose one person who [tosses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_flipping) a fair coin and if it comes up heads then he moves forwards $1$ metre and if tails he moves backwards $1$ metre, then choose another person to do the same; what is the [probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability) $p(d)$ that they will ever be in a line next to each other again?'*.

My solution used a similar technique to the method presented [here](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~jinovak/d.papers/amer.math.monthly.121.08.711.pdf) for finding an expression for [Polya's random walk constants](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolyasRandomWalkConstants.html). I got $p(d)=1-\frac{1}{u(d)}$ (although I'm not 100% sure it's correct), which would mean that for $d$ such that $u(d)$ diverges (since the functions are positive) I would expect $p(d)$ to be $1$, and when $u(d)$ converges I would expect it to be in $[1,\infty)$ giving a legitimate value for $p(d)$. Is this the case, and for what $d$ will $u(d)$ diverge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get that 
$u(d)
=\sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\left[I_{|m|}\left(\frac{t}{d}\right)\right]^d \;\mathrm dt
$
diverges for all $d$.

I'll use the simplest asymptotics
for large $z$
of
$I_a(z)
\approx \dfrac{e^z}{\sqrt{2\pi z}}
$
(note that this is
independent of $a$)
and split each integral
into two parts of
$(0, d)$ and $(d, \infty)$.

Since
$I_a(z)
= \sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(z/2)^{2j+a}}{j!(j+a)!}
$,
for small $z$,
$I_{|m|}(z)
\approx \dfrac{1}{|m|!}+\dfrac{(z/2)^{|m|+2}}{(|m|+1)!} 
$.

If $|z| \le 1$,
$|I_a(z)|
\le \sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(1/2)^{2j+a}}{j!(j+a)!}
= \sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{j!(j+a)!2^{2j+a}}
< \dfrac1{a!2^a}
$.

Let
$v(d)
=\sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_0^d e^{-t}\left[I_{|m|}\left(\frac{t}{d}\right)\right]^d \;\mathrm dt
=\sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}
v_{|m|}(d)
$
where
$v_{m}(d)
=\int_0^d e^{-t}\left[I_{m}\left(\frac{t}{d}\right)\right]^d \;\mathrm dt
$

Similarly, let
$w(d)
=\sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_d^{\infty} e^{-t}\left[I_{|m|}\left(\frac{t}{d}\right)\right]^d \;\mathrm dt
=\sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}
w_{|m|}(d)
$
where
$w_{m}(d)
=\int_d^{\infty} e^{-t}\left[I_{m}\left(\frac{t}{d}\right)\right]^d \;\mathrm dt
$.

Then:

$$|v_{m}(d)|\le\int_0^d e^{-t}\left|I_{m}\left(\frac{t}{d}\right)\right|^d \;\mathrm dt$$
$$\le\frac1{(m!2^m)^d}\int_0^d e^{-t} \;\mathrm dt$$
$$\le\frac1{(m!2^m)^d}$$
so:
$$v(d)\le2\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}
\frac1{(m!2^m)^d}$$

which converges rather violently.

Now comes the interesting part.

$$w_{m}(d)=\int_d^{\infty} e^{-t}\left[I_{m}\left(\frac{t}{d}\right)\right]^d \;\mathrm dt$$
$$\approx\int_d^{\infty} e^{-t}\left[ \dfrac{e^{t/d}}{\sqrt{2\pi t/d}}\right]^d \;\mathrm dt$$
$$= \int_d^{\infty}  \dfrac{1}{(2\pi t/d)^{d/2}} \;\mathrm dt$$
$$= \left(\dfrac{d}{2\pi}\right)^{d/2}\int_d^{\infty}  \dfrac{\mathrm dt}{t^{d/2}}$$

If $d \le 2$,
the integral diverges.

If $d > 2$,
$w_m(d)
\approx  \left(\dfrac{d}{2\pi}\right)^{d/2}\dfrac{d^{1-d/2}}{d/2-1}
=\dfrac{d}{(2\pi)^{d/2}(d/2-1)}
=\dfrac{1}{(2\pi)^{d/2}(1/2-1/d)}
$.

Since all the $w_m(d)$
are asymptotically
independent of $m$
(which surprises me),
the sum of them diverges.

Therefore,
the overall sum diverges.

Comment: Nice answer. +1, including for describing convergence as violent. Could you add some links e.g. for the Bessel function asymptotics?

Comment: I just got it from good old Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function