# For what $d$ does $\sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{d(2n+|m|)}}\binom{2n+|m|}{n}^d$ converge?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, binomial-coefficients

For what (if any) $d\in\mathbb{N}$ does the following expression have a finite value?

$$u(d)=\sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{d(2n+|m|)}}\binom{2n+|m|}{n}^d$$

When I attack it for $d=2$, I can see that the $m=0$ case will be $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n)!^2}{(n!)^4 16^n}$ which diverges if formula $(8)$ in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2038286/accurate-identities-related-to-sum-limits-n-0-infty-frac2nn3x) is correct (Wolfram Alpha [agrees](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20n%3D0%20to%20infinity%20((2n)!%5E2)%2F((16%5En)*(n!%5E4)))). Thus I think $u(d)$ diverges for $d=2$ but I'm not sure how to proceed for larger values of $d$ (for $d=3$ the $m=0$ case is [evaluated](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20n%3D0%20to%20infinity%20((2n)!%5E3)%2F((64%5En)(n!%5E6))) as $\frac{\pi}{\Gamma(\frac{3}{4})^4}$ but Wolfram Alpha doesn't help me with the whole double sum); I assume that [asymptotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis) approximations will have to be used.

For the context of the question, it is very similar to a question I recently asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2089602/for-what-d-does-sum-limits-m-infty-infty-int-0-infty-e-t-lefti). In the present case, I was attacking the following problem (just for fun): *'If $d$ people stand next to each other in a line and play a game where at each step each of them [tosses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_flipping) a fair coin and for each person if he throws heads then he moves forwards $1$ metre and if tails he moves backwards $1$ metre; what is the [probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability) $p(d)$ that they will ever be in a line next to each other again?'*.

Using a similar technique (i.e. using [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function), from the method used in [this paper](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~jinovak/d.papers/amer.math.monthly.121.08.711.pdf)), I got $p(d)=1-\frac{1}{u(d)}$ with $u(d)$ as above. Thus for $d$ such that $u(d)$ diverges $p(d)=1$, and if $u(d)$ converges, then if I am correct it would have to be in $[1,\infty)$ in order for $p(d)$ to be a probability. I would like to know whether this is the case, and for what $d$ will $u(d)$ diverge?

Comment: It would make sense to study how these points spread as the time goes on, then conclude the wanted probability is zero or one by Kolmogorov's theorem and Cantelli's inequality.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio But the wanted probability need not only be zero or one? [Polya's constants](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolyasRandomWalkConstants.html) take on all sorts of values.